# RSS XML feed Warning: simplexml_load_file()

Tags: php, rss, simplexml

I got error message when im trying to fetch data throw simplexml_load_file().

Here is the RSS-fedd:
https://www.svenskafans.com/rss/team/86

Here is the code i used. The code works fine for other RSS-feeds.

```
$rss = simplexml_load_file($url);
    
if($rss)
{
    $items = $rss->channel->item;
    foreach($items as $item)
    {
        $title = $item->title;
        echo $title;
        $link = $item->link;
    }
}
```

Error message:
Warning: simplexml_load_file(): });var f=d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0],j=d.createElement(s),dl=l!='dataLayer'?'&l

Someone know how i can fixed this issue?

Comment: Are you sure that's the full text of the error message? It looks like a bunch of JavaScript code. Maybe the RSS feed is corrupted?

Comment: Also get this error message: 
`Warning: simplexml_load_file(): https://www.svenskafans.com/rss/team/86:16: parser error : EntityRef: expecting ';'`

You can see the rss-feed here: https://www.svenskafans.com/rss/team/86
Can you fetch from this feed?